Fedex API Ship : Error 400 when downloading label PDF via URL
I use the Fedex API to generate shipping labels (https://developer.fedex.com/api/fr-fr/catalog/ship/v1/docs.html) but I can't download the label via the url provided.
Here is the URL :
https://wwwtest.fedex.com/document/v1/cache/retrieve/SH,f15d003851096ec9794972069960_SHIPPING_Z?isLabel=true&autoPrint=false&retrievalMode=THERMAL
Here is the response :
{
    "transactionId": "94bb8cb1-e6d2-430a-a100-9850a57513b2",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "SHIPPING.DOCUMENT.NO.BYTES",
            "message": "We are unable to process this request. Please try again later or contact FedEx Customer Service."
        }
    ]
}

<?php
$url = "https://wwwtest.fedex.com/document/v1/cache/retrieve/SH,f15d003851096ec9794972069960_SHIPPING_Z?isLabel=true&autoPrint=false&retrievalMode=THERMAL";

$arrContextOptions=array(
      "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
?>



could it be you're using the test environment?

Hi, I'm also facing this same issue. Did you get it resolved?
